# Magento 2 - Get product qty and special price from product collection

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-collection, special-price, qty

I am able to get a product collection by using the ProductRepositoryInterface:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
```

Then loop through products by doing:

```
$list = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$items = $list->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {

}
```

I need to get 'qty' and 'special price' from each $item (product). But $item does not provide these methods:

[image]

[image]

As you can see $item is a ProductInterface. And in 'vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc\di.xml' there is this line:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" />
```

So when I call $item->getQty; or $item->getSpecialPrice();  I should get the corresponding values, because both methods are implemented in Magento\Catalog\Model\Product. But this does not work.

In my Block Class I do:

```
 $this->setItems($items);
```

In my phtml file I do:

```
$items = $this->getItems();
if(!empty($items)){
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo "<p> id: ".$item->getId().", name: "
        .$item->getName().", sku: "
        .$item->getSku().", price: ".$item->getPrice()
        .", typeId: ".$item->getTypeId()
        .", visibility: ".$item->getVisibility()
        .", status: ".$item->getStatus()
        .", QTY : ".$item->getQty()
        .", special price: ".$item->getSpecialPrice();
    }
}
```

Everything works, I get all values except for 'getQty()' and 'getSpecialPrice()'.

I absolutely need 'qty' and 'special price' from each product in the collection.

Can someone help ?

**EDIT:**
@Manthan Dave : I did the following, but got an error because getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem() returns NULL:

[image]

Info: the cache was cleared/flushed multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of Qty and Special Price both are external attributes of product,so if you directly called via **$item** then you will not get the value for the same

**Try below code :**

You can get Qty or other values like min qty by using that method.

```
echo $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

OR **Complete Object Data**

```
print_r($item->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData());
```

**clear the cache and check it will works.**

Update :

Load stock interface , **try below code :**

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
   )
  {
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
  }

 $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but got an error (Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQty() on null). Looks like $item-> getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem() returns NULL

Comment: @shahirhajir check this link - https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-product-stock-information-magento-2.html

Comment: @shahirhajir you can also refer this - http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-product-stock-quantity-and-other-stock-information/